# ASP.NET MVC 5 layout trouble with partial View

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a newbie to a MVC world from web form world ( 3 days old :) ) . I created a MVC website which contains a dynamically loaded menu from the DB and load the associated page based on what is clicked.. So far I load menu view on the separate page whose Index action return a View(list of menu items) and the click of each submenu items calls the associated page.. 
I created a new layout page which loads the menu items ( copying the code from menuView)

Here's the _Menu

```
@model IEnumerable<MedicareQA_MVC.Models.spS_MenuItems_Result>

         <div >
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-sm-3 " >
                @{
                    var mainElmnt = Model.Select(o=>o.MenuElementName).Distinct();
                    foreach (var mainNode in mainElmnt)
                    {
                        var elmnts = Model.Where(p => p.MenuElementName == mainNode);
                        <li >@mainNode</li>
                        if( elmnts.Count() >0)
                        {
                         foreach (var elmt in elmnts)
                            {
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked  ">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(elmt.Element,"QADetails","Home",new {id =elmt.RecID },null)  </li>
                                  </ul>
                              }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The page loads correctly but on the click of the menu items i get the following

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List

The menu  controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MenuModel menu = new MenuModel();

    return   View(menu.GetMenu1());
}
```

the _Layout

```
     @model IEnumerable<MedicareQA_MVC.Models.spS_MenuItems_Result>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
            <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/Bootstrap")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 

            <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                    <td class="span12" colspan="2">  <h1>Welcome to our Website</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td class="span4 nav nav-stacked " style="vertical-align:top" >   
                        @Html.Partial("_Menus",Model)


                    </td>
                    <td class="span7">
                            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                            @RenderBody()
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table
```

The page loads fine with the menus. But on event  of clicking the menu I get this run time error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MedicareQA_MVC.Models.QuestionAnswer]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Comment: Show the full error message and some code. Your view has `@model someType`, but you are not passing typeof `someType` to the view, you are passing something else, but without seeing any code its impossible to tell

Comment: I suspect that in your _menulayout view you have your model as a list (ex. @model List<...>). Try removing that line and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Thanks guys... Unfortunately I don't have the code with me.. I will do it once I m at work PC...

Answer (score 0):

```
return   View(menu.GetMenu1());
```

is returning a list of items whereas in view you have used IEnumerable, ie enumerable as model.

Change top line of view to

```
@model List<MedicareQA_MVC.Models.spS_MenuItems_Result>
```

Comment: The view accepts Ienumerable and this should work the same way for

Comment: Point is, what you pass from controller and model you define in view must match. Can you show the GetMenu1() function.. It must be returning List<>

Comment: I changed the Controller to pass an IEnumerable
public IEnumerable<MenuModel> GetMenu()
        {
List<MenuModel> result = new List<MenuModel>();
            mh = new MenuHandler();
   return menuList;
        }

Comment: please post this as edit in question, i am not able to understand what you mentioned in comment. from what i can understand you are still passing menuList, and what is type of menuList is not clear, i think its still List<>

Answer (score 0):

The view accepts Ienumerable and this should work the same way for List.
Moreover i did find a temporary working solution as per dotnetcurry  and I did the following.
Create a div container in the _layout
and call ajax functionality

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            if ($("#menuContainer")[0].innerHTML == "") {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/Menu/MenuLoader")",
                    type: "GET",
                    cache:true,
                    success: function (response) {
                        var container = $("#menuContainer");
                        container.html(response);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("nothing");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

THe menu Controller has the following

> [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
>           public ActionResult MenuLoader()
>           {
>               MenuModel menu = new MenuModel();
>
> ```
>         return  PartialView("_Menus",  menu.GetMenu1());
>     }
> ```

Unfortunately the menu loads after the page loads . Wish there was `<asp:scripthandler>`
 kind of a funcitionality  I could use somewhere around here....

Folks thanks for the support

Comment: That's an awful solution. You need a method (say) `Menu()` decorated with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute that returns your menu, and then in the layout, remove `@model IEnumerable<MedicareQA_MVC.Models.spS_MenuItems_Result>` (a layout should not have a model defined unless if a base view model) and use `@Html.Action("Menu". "YourController")` (not `@Html.Partial`)

Answer (score 0):

Yep that was an awful solution...I finally figured it out. since I dont have the code with me, I can only explain. 
So the issue I had was that I declared the Model at the _MainLayout page. So the menu loaded correctly the first time because the controller had the corresponding Action control. But when I clicked on a menu item it loads another page and another controller which of course did not have the correct model, hence the runtime errors.
The work around.
I removed the Model from the _MainLayout and I called @html.Action("ActionNameToLoadMenu") in the  _MainLayout. The corresponding ActionMethod will return a partial View of the dynamic menu. I repeated the ActionMethod in other controller for the page that was being referenced and it worked. 
Thanks for all your help